# Azure Custom Controller - Doing Login

Tags: c#, visual-studio, api, azure, controller

I have had a MobileService running on Azure, and have decided to implement a login service.

Currently I have Authentication working, and can do migrations/update-database. I am following the TodoItem example. I now want to create my own Custom API, which easily worked on MobileService, but I cannot get it working on Azure Mobile App :/

I have created a new controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[ResponseType(typeof(Cliente))]
[Route("api/Clientes/{Username}/{Senha}")]

private Cliente DoCustomerLogin(string username, string senha)
{
    return db.Clientes.First(x => x.Username == username && x.Senha == senha);
}
```

But i am getting Http 404 error.
How I can solve it?